# Create a Angular material tree structure from Json object

Tags: angular, angular-material, treeview

I have a json object like this

```
{
  "Parent": "Tree",
  "fruit": [
    {
      "fruitNumber": 1,
      "Apple": [
        {
          "appleNumber": 1,
          "Child3": [
            {
              "child3Number": 1,
              "colours": 3,
              "appleColours": [
                {
                  "greenApple": 1
                },
                {
                  "redApple": 2
                },
                {
                  "yelloApple": 3
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As per Angular material tutorial the tree structure should be like this for creating tree view

```
{
    "name": "Tree",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "fruit",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Apple",
            "children": [
              { "name": "greenApple" },
              { "name": "redApple" },
              { "name": "yelloApple" }
            ]
          }
          
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Can anyone guide me how i can create the data structure from given json object

Comment: Would be great if you can share your current attempt, let us know what is the actual issue you faced.

Comment: @YongShun I tried many ways, but didn't get any progress